# Error sending message to DLQ with multi cluster binders

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I have been working on having a setup with 2 kafka binders connected to 2 different clusters based on https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/main/multi-binder-samples/multi-binder-two-kafka-clusters

My setup seems to work wrt to consuming from and publishing to my main topics, but having the issue while sending the message to DLQ.. getting the exception:

```
Error sending to DLQ  a message with key='H90d680e........' and payload= '..........'

Failed to send; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic my_dlq_topic not present in metadata after 60000 ms.
```

springBootVersion = '2.2.6.RELEASE'

springCloudVersion = 'Hoxton.RELEASE'

Comment: Well, did you create that topic?

Comment: These versions are out of support; upgrade to supported versions; if you are still having problems show your code and configuration. https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#support https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-stream#support

Comment: @OneCricketeer. Yes, we do have the dlq topic in both dev and test clusters.When working with the setup involving a single cluster the error messages do get send to dlq.

Comment: @GaryRussell Thanks for the quick response. I'll try to update to more recent versions and see if that fixes my issue.

Comment: Update: Sorry, we are not able to update to more recent versions because the version change is causing update in our db libs as well and this will be a bigger effort at this time for us.